# Kotlin map & reduce array of Strings to Map<String, Any!>

Tags: java, kotlin

I want to create Kotlin utility accessible from Java that converts list of Strings to Map. So far I've written:

```
class Utils {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic fun values(item: GSAItem): Map<String, Object> {
            return item.itemDescriptor.propertyNames.map {it -> Map.Entry<String, Any!>(it, item.getPropertyValue(it)) };            }
    }
}
```

But I'm getting error

```
Error:(16, 74) Kotlin: Unresolved reference: Entry
```

GSAItem.getPropertyValue is Java method which takes String as argument and returns Object. After that I suspect I need to find some equivalent of collect function from Java 8?

Comment: What is the `KeyStore` class?

Comment: @yole I'm guessing it's this [KeyStore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html). `KeyStore.Entry` is a marker interface. Did you mean to use `PrivateKeyEntry`, `SecretKeyEntry` or `TrustedCertificateEntry` instead?

Comment: Oops, sorry. I've tried different imports and eventually pasted wrong code. I've edited it to match what was original version.

Comment: Please don't use empty classes with `companion object`s. Use plain `object`s or make the function top-level and consider making it an extension function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Map.Entry - stdlib - Kotlin Programming Language](http://Map.Entry%20-%20stdlib%20-%20Kotlin%20Programming%20Language) is an `interface` and as such it does not have a constructor which is why you are getting an error (perhaps not the best message). You can find an implementation, make your own, or use [`associate`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/associate.html) instead:

```
class Utils {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic fun values(item: GSAItem): Map<String, Any?> {
            return item.itemDescriptor.propertyNames.associate { it to item.getPropertyValue(it) }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you should use `Any` or `Any?` instead of `java.lang.Object`.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
item.itemDescriptor
    .propertyNames
    .map { name -> name to item.getPropertyValue(name) }
    .toMap()
```